# How do I set custom ListView in Android using Firebase? I am facing issue while using custom ListView with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am receiving data from Firebase in a custom list view, but I am facing issue that it is showing error

```
04-22 23:20:27.890 13718-13718/com.example.kapilmehta.fundamentalsofeconomics E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kapilmehta.fundamentalsofeconomics, PID: 13718
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.kapilmehta.fundamentalsofeconomics.Model
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.kapilmehta.fundamentalsofeconomics.Practice$1.onDataChange(Practice.java:54)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
04-22 23:20:27.920 13718-13718/com.example.kapilmehta.fundamentalsofeconomics I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13718 SIG: 9
```

This is Model class:

```
public class Model {

    String ques, ans;

    public Model() {
    }

    public Model(String ques, String ans) {
        this.ques = ques;
        this.ans = ans;
    }

    public String getQues() {
        return ques;
    }

    public void setQues(String ques) {
        this.ques = ques;
    }

    public String getAns() {
        return ans;
    }

    public void setAns(String ans) {
        this.ans = ans;
    }
}
```

This is Fragment where I have received the data from Firebase:

```
public class Practice extends Fragment {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> list;
    Model model;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    public Practice() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_practice,container,false);
        listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_practice);

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Quiz");
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        model = new Model();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),R.layout.grid_layout_custom,R.id.text_ques,list);


        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    model = ds.getValue(Model.class);
                    Log.d("Tag",model.getQues()+"\n"+model.getAns());
                    list.add(model.getQues().toString()+"\n\n\n"+model.getAns().toString());
                }
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: please, post your firebase structure as well :)

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should show your firebase data structure (it must the same with data model).

- first hint: You can log variable "ds" for debug what data you received from firebase.
- second hint: Don't put your firebase query code in getView method, You should retrieve firebase data in other place and notify data for listview after. Because firebase task is a low task, put it inside a UI render method will make your app "not response"